# itemize environment fails within fixme note

Tags: itemize, fixme

I'm having problems when I try to enclose an itemize environment within a fxnote (using the package fixme). The code is attached below, as indicated tests 1 and 2 works fine, but test 3 fails when uncommented giving a long error message reproduced below).

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Test 1
\fxnote{this is ok}

\bigskip

Test 2
\begin{itemize}
    \item This is also ok
\end{itemize}

\bigskip

Test 3
%\fxnote{
%\begin{itemize}
%    \item This doesnt work when uncommented
%\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

Is this a known problem with the fixme package? Is there some way to fix this or alternatively another package that can do the same as fixme?

thanks in advance, Kasper

PS And here is the error message I get

```
Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log.
 main.tex, line 25
Use of \@xmpar doesn't match its definition.

\@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.25 \end{itemize}}

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

 main.tex, line 25
Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.

\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.25 \end{itemize}}

If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

 main.tex
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 25.

<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> main.tex

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 987 strings out of 492164
 14565 string characters out of 6125314
 80945 words of memory out of 5000000
 5406 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5100 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 36i,3n,62p,193b,282s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

 main.tex, line 25
Underfull \hbox (badness 1
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks! I have often found the answer to many Latex questions here -- in fact I never had to ask a question until now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. You can handle it using fixme annotation *environments* like anfxnote.

Try writing:

```
\begin{anfxnote}{<short summary of note>}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Now it works!
\end{itemize}
\end{anfxnote}
```